# When I custom ToolbarSize,How can I keep navigationicon center in vertical?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, toolbar

I am using Toolbar as follow:

```
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

It works well.
But when I fix acionbarSize to 50dp in Theme,navigation icon do not in the center .How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually,I used AppCompatActivity(support v7 22.1.+) instead of AcionbarActivity and it was solved.